# How to stop blocking queue size from increasing in thread pool executor service?

Tags: java, multithreading

Let’s say, I have a service A which has a thread pool executor to call service B. We can set the core pool size and queue of that pool with our own values.  Now, service B is slow in responding to requests due to which the active threads in service A threadpool increases which result in increasing the blocking queue size. How can I prevent the queue size of service A from growing?

Setting

Comment: Rule of thumb is keep either threads constant with changing queue size or keep the queue size constant with changing number of threads. So, ideally, going with fixedThreadPool + LinkedBlockingQueue or cachedThreadPool + ArrayBlockingQueue is good. If you want to prevent blocking queue size to not grow beyond a limit, use a *bounded blocking queue*

Answer (score 0):

There are several constructors for [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) that accept a [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).

`BlockingQueue` is an interface. One implementation is [ArrayBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html), which has a bounded size.

The documentation for `ThreadPoolExecutor` mentions this explicitly:

> **3. Bounded queues.** A bounded queue (for example, an ArrayBlockingQueue) helps prevent resource exhaustion when used with finite maximumPoolSizes, but can be more difficult to tune and control. ...